# refresh jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

how can i refresh a jsp page from other jsp page
i have a jsp (jsp1) page that hold 2 frame of jsp
i need that the jsp (jsp2) will refresh the other jsp (jsp3)

and another question same one as above only with servlet
how can i make a servlet page refresh a jsp page

Comment: Keep in mind that JSP is a view technology which runs at webserver and generates/outputs HTML to the webbrowser. This should clear out some misconceptions. Your answer is basically in the HTML corner.

Answer (score 4):

Refreshing is a purely client-side concept. So you must do it with javascript:

```
location.reload(true)
```