# refresh a jsp / webpage

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a single jsp which determines when a button is pressed and then runs a sql:update, this is working fine.

However I then need to force a refresh and any attempt to reload() directly or enter script tags (to call a function) inside my if clause fails (Eclipse).

Probably not the best code in the world.

```
<input type="submit" value="Change" name="update"/>
</td>

<% 
String x = request.getParameter("update");
 if("Change".equals(x))
  {
  %>

   <sql:update var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/database">
   insert into logs (ts, rssi, node, asset, ack) 
   values (now(), 1000, <%=number%>, <%=asset%>, 1);
  </sql:update>  

Now refresh the page

  <%
   }
  %>
```

The correct way to refresh is eluding me (the rest of the code was simple in comparison).

Assistance appreciated.

Regards
Ralph

Comment: Refreshing is a purely client-side concept. So you must do it with javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [refresh jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777848/refresh-jsp-page)

Comment: Indeed, but how do I call a javascript function from within the if clause.

Comment: you can't. what you can do is redirect to the same page

Comment: Please elaborate Philipp, I understand window.location.reload etc but not how I can call this within my if clause (the refresh must only occur after the button is pushed and the sql:update has run)

Comment: you can't call javascript from withing your JSP! it's impossible. javascript runs in the clients browser and JSP runs on your server. your only options is to redirect to the same page in JSP

Comment: response.sendRedirect throws an illegal state exception

Comment: `location.reload();` use this javascript to refresh page.